# Is the work integral decomposable?

Tags: vector-analysis, classical-mechanics, line-integrals

Work is defined as $W = \int_{\gamma} \vec F \cdot d\vec l$ which I think means $W = \int (F_x, F_y, F_z) \cdot (dx, dy, dz)$.  So by the linearity of the integral, could we always decompose work into the integrals in each of the directions $x,y,z$?  As in, does $W = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} F_xdx + \int_{y_0}^{y_1} F_ydy + \int_{z_0}^{z_1} F_zdz$?  Because that seems easier to compute (at least sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how it differs from the usual method. I suppose you mean the first integral depends on $x$ only, the second one on $y$ only and the third one on $z$ only, so that simplifies the calculation. But this is not true.
In fact, $F_x$ is not a function of $x$, it is not even a function of $x$, $y$, $z$, but a function of time $t$. So at last, you need to write everything it in terms of the parameter $t$. So that's the same way it's usually done, exactly that you write it explicitly as the sum of three integrals.

Besides, there are some problems in your using such a notation. For example, if the particle moves along a closed path, do you write $\int_{x_0}^{x_0}$ etc.? That will suggest that the work done is always zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can correctly write
$$W = \int_\gamma F_x\,dx + \int_\gamma F_y\,dy + \int_\gamma F_z\,dz.$$

But note that this is still tracing the path $\gamma$, so 
$\int_\gamma F_x\, dx$ is not a univariate integration in the general case.
If $F_x$ is a function of $x$ only,
then you *can* write $\int_\gamma F_x\, dx = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} F_x\, dx,$
but that's a very restrictive condition.
It requires at a very minimum that the force is conservative,
so that how much work is done is a function only of the starting and ending points;
in particular, if you end at the starting point then the work done is zero.
But there are plenty of conservative force fields that still don't
satisfy the condition.

The condition *is* satisfied for all three variables in a uniform force field,
in a paraboloid "bowl" force field (radial force everywhere with $F \sim r^2$),
and in some other force fields that you might construct with
$\mathbf F = f_x(x)\mathbf{\hat x} + f_y(y)\mathbf{\hat y} + f_z(z)\mathbf{\hat z},$
but I can't think of any examples right now (other than the ones already given)
that still satisfy the condition for an arbitrary choice of axes.